# Propensity score matching at the group level and models at the subject level

Tags: mixed-model, causality, propensity-scores, validity

I am running a study that uses a combination of propensity score matching and mixed-effects models. I use propensity score matching to locate some groups (half of them represent control, and another half represent treatment) based on group-level measurements. Then I use mixed-effects models to understand the effect of the treatment on DVs at the subject level (the random effect is the group id). And I want to make causal inferences on how the treatment (at the group level) leads to changes in the DVs (at the subject level).

Reviewers are critical of PSM because of the limitations of this method itself. And they are more concerned about matching with group-level measurements and modeling with subject-level measurements. They suggest me to make better arguments and thoroughly discuss the threat to validity of my methodology.

Can someone help me with this? I understand that this methodology is not perfect but it's the best considering the research question and the data I have.

Comment: This article explains a method for doing exactly this without propensity scores:  [Zubizarreta & Keele (2017)](https://doi.org/10.1080/01621459.2016.1240683).

Comment: @Noah Thanks! I might consider applying this method in my future studies. However, for the current study, I only have time to polish the arguments, unpacking the limitations and making more conservative causal inferences.